# Puppeteer selector always returns data

Tags: javascript, testing, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I am trying to make sure that app does not render anything before response is received. My test case is

```
it.only("should postpone render rendering", async function () {
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        const requestHandler = (request) => {
            if (request.method() === "GET" && request.url() === LOGIN_METHODS_API) {
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    request.respond({
                        // returning response
                    });
                    page.off("request", requestHandler);
                    await page.setRequestInterception(false);
                }, 3000);
            } else {
                request.continue();
            }
        };
        page.on("request", requestHandler);
        await Promise.all([
            page.goto(
                `${TEST_CLIENT_BASE_URL}${DEFAULT_WEBSITE_BASE_PATH}/route-that-fetches-data`
            ),
            page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" }),
        ]);
        const component = await page.waitForSelector(SELECTOR_CONSTANT, {
            visible: true,
            timeout: 1000,
        });
        assert.deepStrictEqual(component, null);
    });
});
```

I have tried running tests in headed mode, rendering is delayed as expected, id selector and element is absent in the DOM, however assertion fails with component having something like

```
+ ElementHandle {
+   _client: <ref *1> CDPSession {
+     _callbacks: Map(0) {},
+     _connection: <ref *10> Connection {
+       _callbacks: Map(0) {},
+       _closed: false,
+       _delay: 0,
+       _lastId: 35,
+       _sessions: Map(1) {
+         'C0FD58BE0172E55D60032D88F3644B80' => [Circular *1]
+       },
+       _transport: NodeWebSocketTransport {
+         _ws: <ref *2> WebSocket {
+           [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
+           _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
+           _bufferedAmount: 0,
+           _closeCode: 1006,
+           _closeFrameReceived: false,
+           _closeFrameSent: false,
+           _closeMessage: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
+           _closeTimer: null,
+           _events: [Object: null prototype] {
+             close: [Function: onClose] {
+               [Symbol(kIsForOnEventAttribute)]: false,
+               [Symbol(kListener)]: [Function (anonymous)]
+             },
// and so on...
```

What is wrong with this case and is there any other way to check if element is not present in the DOM, maybe method like react-testing-library has (not.toBe.inDocument)

Comment: This seems like an unusual test. If your `page.goto` loads a resource, you flush out all resource requests with networkidle0, then you wait for an element to show up. So of course it'll show up, because every Puppeteer call you're making is geared completely towards waiting for stuff. I suppose you could stall the response and wait for domcontentloaded, then use `page.$` to check whether the element is in the DOM before the response arrives, but this seems like a rather odd test. I wouldn't bother. As before, it's sort of hard to write a concrete, verified, runnable answer without a [mcve].

Comment: agreed test is odd, but i need to make sure that component is not rendered before response is received, and make sure that is does once i have the response

Comment: Why not just make sure it's rendered when the response arrives? That's the usual test. If the data isn't there, what are the chances of accidentally rendering the data? None, right? As mentioned in your last question as well, `page.waitForRequest` should be much simpler than messing with toggling interception on and off, then `page.on`, `page.off`. Another nitpick/gotcha: the extra `waitForNetworkIdle` isn't needed. `goto`s already have a `waitUntil: "networkidle0"` option you can use, then you can remove the `Promise.all` as well. Waiting for navs twice can create bugs.

Comment: The last nitpick is discussed in [this blog post](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation).